# Не работает форма обратной связи html, php

Tags: php, html, форма

Я никогда разработкой сайтов не занималась, но вот пришлось:)
Сайт dona-tela.by
Форма в самом низу. В приложении обработчик данных. 
Эта форма уже была встроена в шаблон. Но я пробовала и 2 другие, тоже не работали.

Привязываю доменную почту.

Писала на хостинг. вот что ответили:

> Цитата

При отправке с помощью PHP функции mail() в качестве адреса отправителя указан адрес на домене, не совпадающем с доменом сайта.

Это именно ваш случай.

Почтовый сервер получателя отказывается принимать письмо, так как в заголовке FROM (адрес отправителя) в письме указан адрес "snsnsm@mail.ru";, хотя в действительности письмо отправляется не от mail.ru.
В качестве адреса отправителя необходимо указывать адрес на домене, на котором размещен сайт, т.е. "dona-tela.by".

В заголовке письма FROM Вам необходимо всегда указывать адрес отправителя на домене dona-tela.by.

К сожалению, мы не можем Вам помочь в написании и отладке скриптов, размещаемых на сервере. Для этого Вам следует обращаться к разработчику сайта.

```html
<?php

/* Задаем переменные */
$name = "Письмо Сайта";
$email = "info@dona-tela.by";
$tel = htmlspecialchars($_POST["tel"]);
$website = htmlspecialchars($_POST["website"]);
$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST["message"]);
$bezspama = htmlspecialchars($_POST["bezspama"]);

/* Ваш адрес и тема сообщения */
$address = "info@dona-tela.by";
$sub = "Сообщение с сайта ХХХ";

/* Формат письма */
$mes = "Сообщение с сайта dona-tela.by.\n
Имя отправителя: $name 
Электронный адрес отправителя: $email
Телефон отправителя: $tel
Сайт отправителя: $website
Текст сообщения:
$message";


if (empty($bezspama)) /* Оценка поля bezspama - должно быть пустым*/
{
/* Отправляем сообщение, используя mail() функцию */
$from  = "From: Письмо Сайта <info@dona-tela.by> \r\n Reply-To: info@dona-tela.by \r\n";
if (mail($address, $sub, $mes, $from)) {
    header('Refresh: 5; URL=https://dona-tela.by');
    echo '
    
    Письмо отправлено, через 5 секунд вы вернетесь на сайт Dona-tela.by';}
else {
    header('Refresh: 5; URL=https://dona-tela.by');
    echo '
    
    Письмо не отправлено, через 5 секунд вы вернетесь на сайт Dona-tela.by';}
}
exit; /* Выход без сообщения, если поле bezspama заполнено спам ботами */
?>
```

Comment: Совет №1 : Не показывайте код скриншотами, а копируйте и здесь вставляйте.

Comment: готово, я просто здесь тоже впервые))

Answer (score 0):

Что бы указать отправителя просто поменяйте

```
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
```

На свои данные, так как именно они именют отправителя в вашем коде

Например поставьте их

```
$name = "Письмо Сайта";
$email = "info@dona-tela.by";
```

А вот уже переменная $address содержит того кто примет письмо.

Менять переменные что бы приходило письмо с верными данными следует после

```
/* Формат письма */
$mes = "Сообщение с сайта dona-tela.by.\n
Имя отправителя: $name 
Электронный адрес отправителя: $email
Телефон отправителя: $tel
Сайт отправителя: $website
Текст сообщения:
$message";
```

Или просто поменяйте строку

```
$from  = "From: $name <$email> \r\n Reply-To: $email \r\n";
```

На

```
$from  = "From: Письмо Сайта <info@dona-tela.by> \r\n Reply-To: info@dona-tela.by \r\n";
```

Вот такой функцией я отправляю письма на своих проектах

```
function send($to, $subj, $text, $from_name = null, $from_address = null, $encoding = 'UTF-8', $is_html = true) {
    $mime = 'text/' . ($is_html ? 'html' : 'plain');

    $from_name = empty($from_name) ? "Отправлено с Сайта" :$from_name;
    $from_address = empty($from_address) ? "noreply@walfter.ru" : $from_address;
    $headers = "From: {$from_name} <{$from_address}>\r\n"
        . "Content-type: {$mime}; charset={$encoding}\r\n"
        . "Mime-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $subj = '=?' . $encoding . '?B?' . base64_encode($subj) . '?=';
    return mail($to, $subj, $text, $headers);
}
```

Попробуйте ей... Но по идее и ваши заголовки нормально подходили

Comment: Добавила в вопрос новый код с поправками. Попробовала применить на сайте - не помогло:(

Comment: @СнежанаМожейко в спам приходит? Ящик сменился? Если сменился ящик и приходит в спам то думаю может быть потому что вы отправляете его сами себе

Comment: ящик info@dona-tela.by , в спаме нет

Comment: Вообще письмо не пришло?

Comment: Да, не приходит вообще

Comment: А вас хостер не заблокировал за рассылку спама? Обычно отключают функцию mail()

Comment: нет, там не так много пробных было, да и в спам ни разу ничего не приходило. и капча стоит

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

/* Задаем переменные */
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
$tel = htmlspecialchars($_POST["tel"]);
$website = htmlspecialchars($_POST["website"]);
$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST["message"]);
$bezspama = htmlspecialchars($_POST["bezspama"]);

/* Ваш адрес и тема сообщения */
$address = "info@dona-tela.by";
$sub = "Сообщение с сайта ХХХ";

/* Формат письма */
$mes = "Сообщение с сайта dona-tela.by.\n
Имя отправителя: $name 
Электронный адрес отправителя: $email
Телефон отправителя: $tel
Сайт отправителя: $website
Текст сообщения:
$message";


if (empty($bezspama)) /* Оценка поля bezspama - должно быть пустым*/
{
/* Отправляем сообщение, используя mail() функцию */
if (mail($address, $sub, $mes)) {
    header('Refresh: 5; URL=https://dona-tela.by');
    echo '

    Письмо отправлено, через 5 секунд вы вернетесь на сайт Dona-tela.by';}
else {
    header('Refresh: 5; URL=https://dona-tela.by');
    echo '

    Письмо не отправлено, через 5 секунд вы вернетесь на сайт Dona-tela.by';}
}
exit; /* Выход без сообщения, если поле bezspama заполнено спам ботами */
?>
```

Comment: У вас отправитель не меняется, отправитель меняется в заголовках

Comment: @Walfter предполагаю, что на хостинге установлен отправитель по умолчанию. И если не задавать заголовок явно, будет установлен адрес отправителя, заданный для текущего пользователя.

Comment: @Walfter а в Вашем ответе, Вы предлагаете изменить данные, которые отправляет пользователь сайта в обратной связи. И узнать имя и email пользователя теперь будет невозможно.

Comment: Почитайте полностью, я в ответе об этом говорил и даже сказал когда менять

Comment: @Walfter действительно, Вы правы! Но, как и я, автор вопроса этого не заметила. В этом можно убедиться, посмотрев обновленный код в вопросе.